# Does SO-Dimm DDR3L RAM work in an SDRAM DDR3L slot

Tags: memory, ddr3

I want to upgrade my laptop ram HP notebook 15-ay000nk 4GB ram to 8GB.. and I find only this ram in my country so I want to know if it will be working or not

This is my ram 4 GB DDR3L-1600 SDRAM (1 x 4 GB)

---

This is the ram which i will buy 
Team Group DDR3L SODIMM memory module

```
4 GB capacity
Frequency 1600 MHz
Voltage 1.35 Volts
```

Will it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

HP seems to avoid specifying the RAM as SODIMM, but I'm pretty sure your RAM is.
If the length of the module is about 67.6 mm then it is SODIMM. With a length of about 135 mm it would be a normal DIMM.

The L in DDR3L means it can run with low voltage of 1.35V.
This fact is important too for laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Should work.
HP doesn't say so explicitly but the slots in the laptop take a maximum of 2 SO-DIMM's of up to 8 GB each. (So you can use 2x8 for 16 in total.)

It HAS to be DDR3L (without the L won't work) and speeds of 1600 Mhz and 1866 Mhz are both possible, but you shouldn't mix speeds. Both SO-DIMMs should be same speed.
They don't have to be the same size, but the laptop will be slightly faster (5% or so, not really noticable) if both SO-DIMMs are the same size. You will actually benefit more from the larger RAM capacity than from that minor speed increase.